# How to avoid multiple events on one object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events, keydown

I'm making a picture preview of a link typed in a text box. jQuery is used to send back in a preview `<div>` the pictures. When multiple pictures, i'm trying to make a navigation to select the picture you want with left right keys.

So i'm adding events to `document` to capture keys typed. This is done in the `success` of my ajax request (because it's async).

My problem is that when the first request is done everything is ok. After the first time, event is fired 2 times, then 3 times; one additional time after each request.

I tried to unbind but it has no effect.

#### Code:

```
$.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "curl.php",
            data: {"lien" : lien},
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#result").html("");
                if(data && data != ""){
                var images = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#result").html("<img src='"+images[0].nom+"' />");
                console.log("Nombre d'images : "+images.length);
                if(nav){
                    $(document).unbind('keydown');
                    console.log('détruit');
                }
                function nav() {
            $(document).bind('keydown', function(e){    
              switch(e.which)
                {case 37:
                    if(imagePosition>0){imagePosition--;}else{imagePosition = 0;};
                    console.log(imagePosition);
                    $("#result").html("<img src='"+images[imagePosition].nom+"' />");
                    return false;
                 break; 
                 case 39:
                    if(imagePosition<(images.length-1)){imagePosition++;}else{imagePosition = (images.length-1)  };
                    console.log(imagePosition);
                    $("#result").html("<img src='"+images[imagePosition].nom+"' />");
                    return false;
                 break;      
                 }   
                }); 
            }//fin de nav
                nav();
                }
                
            }
     })
```

- `imagePosition` is the number to select the picture in the returned array.
- `image` is the array with links of the picture gathered.
- `nav()` is the fonction that attach the event to the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
```

please try and use

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function(e){
```

Though this is not the ideal way, this will gurantee that before you attach a handler to an event on an element, the other handlers for the same event are removed.

Comment: I've clicked the check box. One last question, would the .live event be more apropriate for this ?

Comment: Thanks. As you are binding to "document" which is always there, I don't think you would need live event in this case. You ideally want to refactor your code a bit. That should solve the problem out.